# How to use PendingIntent for two different activities?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am using PendingIntent to take user from push notifications to Activity B i,e when user clicks on notification it will go to screen B.

I want it to be screen B only when application is loaded and running, else it should go to screen A. I have implemented this as well.

Now, there is scenario, wherein I have received the notifications, hence the intent is set to Screen B, but I haven't clicked it. If I kill the application process using DDMS or if the android kills the application **before I click on notification** and then I click it, it tries to load activity B which is not what I want in this case. I would like to load activity A in this case which is first sceen of the app.

Please, suggest what to do !

Comment: Your question is not clear.Can you please elaborate your use-case

Comment: can you elaborate your question  some more with source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're deciding whether to launch activity A or B at the time you post the notification, which, as you've discovered, will not work: once you submit the notification to the Notification Manager, you can't make changes to it.

The way to do this is to always launch the same activity, but have that activity potentially redirect the user to a different activity based on whatever criteria you want. For example, you could launch activity B, which then bounces the user immediately to A if the app is not already in the foreground. (You could also do this with a third activity whose job is simply to route the user around, or with a service, or with a broadcast.)

Now the decision about where to send the user is made at the time the user taps on the notification, rather than at the time the notification is posted.